# how can i GET request parameters in a URL that contains another parameter?

Tags: php

> i can't able to get the value of parameter which contains another
>   parameter.

URL:

> https://mysite.com/test/1234?basic=2&email=utm_source%3Dmobpartner%26utm_medium%3Dcpa%26utm_campaign%3D4gt44t4

tell me how to get the utm_campaign value.

Comment: I think utm_campaign is part of `email`. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working at https://eval.in/95483

First you need to urldecode your encoded values:

```
$string = urldecode($_GET['email']);
```

then use parse_str() to create an array from that:

```
parse_str($string, $ary);
```

Here is the example code from the link I provided:

```
$email='utm_source%3Dmobpartner%26utm_medium%3Dcpa%26utm_campaign%3D4gt44t4';
$string = urldecode($email);
$ary=array();
parse_str($string, $ary);
var_dump($ary);
```

At that point you can call `$ary['utm_campaign']`.

Answer (score 1):

The value of $_['utm_source'] is a URL encoded string, so you need to URL decode it. Then you can put into an associative array to extract the value of 'utm_campaign':

```
<?php
 parse_str(urldecode($_GET['utm_source']),$output);
 echo $output['utm_campaign'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should separate every argument by a `&`.

Like this :
https://mysite.com/test/1234?basic=2&email=&utm_source=mobpartner&utm_medium=cpa&utm_campaign=4gt44t4

This will yield a $_GET variable like this :

```
$_GET['email'] = '';
$_GET['utm_source'] = 'mobpartner';
$_GET['utm_medium'] = 'cpa';
$_GET['utm_campaign'] = '4gt44t4';
```

Answer (score -1):

What you're saying is that you want to get the '4gt44t4', is that?

A $_GET['utm_campaign'] doesn't work?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's not a parameter in the query string.

Comment: Hmm, so it's coming in a form? I mean, if you try POST instead of GET, it still doesn't work?

Comment: @Dimas Pante, your code will never work. If you look closely at the URL, the ONLY parameter is $_GET['utm_source']. This parameter contains a URL encoded string.

Comment: Yeah, I see that. First I was trying to get what he means with parameter inside parameter, but then I got it.. duh hehe